# JPA boolean discriminator

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, jpa

I want to map in JPA 2.1 (on Hibernate 5.0.2 with MySQL database if that's relevant) a single table to two classes. I know that's done with `SINGLE_TABLE` inheritance + `@DiscriminatorColumn` and `@DiscriminatorValue`.

However, I wanted to discriminate based on a boolean column (well, boolean field in the mapping, I'm not sure how the database handles that). `DiscriminatorType` only contains 3 values (`String`, `Char`, and `Integer`) none of which seem particularly correct for my requirement. I could, I suppose, change my discriminator column to a more standard type, but I really do only need a boolean distinction and do not care how does the database store that info.

While a good workaround for MySQL 5.5 (which I would imagine looks something like `use Char and write "0" and "1" as values, due to how it stores values it'll cast correctly`) would be appreciated, I feel like database agnostic solution is in order.

Comment: I think going for `INTEGER` and considering 0 = false, 1 = true should cover every database.

Comment: @Tunaki nope, doesn't work for Postgres.

and OP, great call on the implicit cast workaround! Postgres doesn't allow 0 or 1 for true and false, but it does implicitly cast strings "true" and "false"